# Inverting density in favour of fugacity

Tags: statistical-mechanics, bosons

In these [notes](http://www.damtp.cam.ac.uk/user/tong/statphys/three.pdf) on pages 80 and 81 the following step was used

The density in terms of fugacity is 
$$
\frac{N}{V} = \frac{z}{\lambda^3}\left ( 1+ \frac{z}{2 \sqrt{2}} + \ldots \right )
$$

and this is inverted to 
$$
z = \frac{\lambda^3 N}{V} \left ( 1 - \frac{1}{2 \sqrt{2}} \frac{\lambda^3 N}{V} +\ldots \right )
$$
Using the approximation that $z$ and $\lambda^3N/V$ are much less than 1. Frankly I'm bewildered by what they did. Would someone be able to explain?

Comment: The first equation is quadratic in $z$. Solve it to get $z=z(N/V)$. Finally, expand $z(N/V)$ in powers of $(N/V)$ to get the result. Anyway, this question is about mathematics, not physics. Next time consider [Math.SE](http://www.math.stackexchange.com) instead of Physics.SE.

Comment: Ah thanks. I didn't notice your response but you have confirmed what I did.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $\phi(z)=\sum_{k\geq 1} a_k z^k$ be absolutely convergent and invertible in a neighborhood of $z=0$, with $a_1\neq 0$. Let us denote its (compositional) inverse by $\phi^{-1}(u)=\sum_{k\geq 1} b_k u^k$.
It is not difficult to check that the following relations hold (see below):
$$
\sum_{n=1}^m a_n\sum_{\substack{k_1,\dots,k_n\geq 1\\ k_1+\cdots +k_n=m}}
\prod_{i=1}^n b_{k_i}
=
\begin{cases}
1&\text{ if }m=1\,,\\
0&\text{ otherwise.}
\end{cases}
\tag{1}
$$
From this, it is easy to express the coefficients $(b_k)_{k\geq 1}$ in terms of the coefficients $(a_k)_{k\geq 1}$. One thus obtains, for example:
$$
b_1=\frac{1}{a_1},\quad
b_2=-\frac{a_2}{a_1^3},\quad
b_3=2\frac{a_2^2}{a_1^5}-\frac{a_3}{a_1^4},
\quad\text { etc. }
$$
In your case, you have $u=N/V$ and
$$
a_1=1/\lambda^3,\quad a_2=1/(2\sqrt{2}\lambda^3).
$$
Appying the above, one then gets
$$
b_1 = \lambda^3,\quad b_2=-\lambda^6/(2\sqrt{2}),
$$
as desired. Note that this approach can be used to extract the series for the (compositional) inverse to arbitrary order.

---

Let me briefly explain how relation (1) is derived. On the one 
hand, by definition,
$$
\phi(\phi^{-1}(u)) = u.
\tag{2}
$$
On the other hand,
\begin{eqnarray}
\phi(\phi^{-1}(u))
&=&
\sum_{n\geq 1} a_n \Bigl( \sum_{k\geq 1} b_k u^k \Bigr)^n \\
&=&
a_1 b_1 u + (a_1 b_2 + a_2 b_1^2) u^2 + \ldots \\
&=&
\sum_{m\geq 1} \Bigl\{ \sum_{n=1}^m a_n 
\sum_{\substack{k_1,\ldots,k_n\geq 1\\k_1+\cdots+k_n=m}} \prod_{i=1}^n b_{k_i} 
\Bigr\} u^m.
\tag{3}
\end{eqnarray}
It only remains to match the coefficients in the two expressions (2) and (3): the coefficient of $u$ must be $1$, and therefore
$$
a_1 b_1 = 1 \implies b_1 = 1/a_1.
$$
The coefficient of $u^2$ (and all higher powers of $u$) must be $0$, from which we deduce that
$$
a_1 b_2 + a_2 b_1^2 = 0 \implies b_2 = - a_2 b_1^2 / a_1 = - a_2 / a_1^3. 
$$
Proceeding in the same way for the coefficient of $u^m$ 
yields (1).

Answer (score 0):

Ok. After experimenting a bit I think I answered the question, although confirmation would be useful.

I will write $N\lambda^3/V = \alpha$ and $1/2 \sqrt{2} = \gamma$ so that we have 
$$ 
\alpha = z + \gamma z^2
$$
or that
$$ 
z = \frac{-1 + \sqrt{1+ 4\gamma \alpha}}{2\gamma}
$$
Taylor expanding to second order, 
$$
-\frac{1}{2 \gamma} + \frac{1}{2 \gamma}+ \frac{\frac12 4 \gamma \alpha}{2 \gamma} -\frac{ \frac14 (4\gamma)^2 \alpha^2}{4 \gamma} 
$$
or
$$
\alpha -\gamma \alpha^2 = \frac{\lambda^3 N}{V} \left ( 1 - \frac{1}{2 \sqrt{2}} \frac{\lambda^3 N}{V} \right)
$$